# How to fix the connected edge problem?

Tags: modifiers

[image][image]

The picture on the right should be the right result. I am following a tutorial.
Mine is on the left. There are gaps on the top and bottom, they would not close up. Can anyone help?

I used Array modifier and use an Arrow empty to make the circle closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did twist the value of the Merge, but it still gave me problems. Until I set a small value then set a bigger value then set a small value again, it finally worked. Maybe it is a bug on mine.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to check "Merge" And also "First and Last" in the array modifier. You can tweak the merge distance if there is still a gap. Your relative distance should be 1.00 on the array axis for it to work out of the box.

Alternatively, with Blender 2.82 and onward, you can use the weld modifier and set the distance threshold accordingly. This modifier merges vertices which are closer than the threshold.

Comment: ... also, make sure any subdivision is _below_ the array.

Comment: I did check MERGE and FIRST AND LAST but it does not do anything. and if the DISTANCE is 1, then the shape becomes deformed, uploaded above.

Comment: Did you by any chance tweak the "auto smooth" angle settings in the object info ?

Comment: No. I did not use it.